# What is the difference between these two object methods in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Consider the following code:

```
function someObj() {
    this.someFunction = function() {
        console.log('someFunction');
    }
}

someObj.prototype.foo = function() {
    console.log('foo');
}
```

I can call both like so:

```
var test = new someObj();
test.someFunction();     // Logs 'someFunction'
test.foo();              // Logs 'foo'
```

How would variable scope be affected here? Is there an advantage / disadvantage to each approach?

Comment: Thank you, this can be closed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work?rq=1

Comment: *"How would variable scope be affected here?"* JavaScript has lexical scope. So the function stored in `this.someFunction` has access to all variables declared in `someObj`, while `someObj.prototype.foo` doesn't.